# How do map 1-to-1 relationship in grails to just 1 table under the covers?

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm, one-to-one

Let's say I have a UserAccount domain class that has a UserPreferences domain class. I do this to separate the fields for organization purposes. Is there a way to tell grails/gorm that I really want it to map these domain classes to just the user_account table under the covers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an

```
static embedded = []
```

It is described [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.2%20Composition%20in%20GORM).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed and couldn't find it in the extra gorm info. I guess they presented this idea early on in the docs rather than in the customizing part, which is where I thought it should be.